# Cannot `cd` to E: drive using Windows CMD command line

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, storage, usb-storage

I connected a camera to Windows machine through USB, but I am unable to access the device when I type "cd E:\" through command line.

I can see the device through file explorer, and the drive letter appears as E.

The images below illustrate what I am trying to communicate:

[image: Screenshot of command line access window]

[image: Windows file explorer at This Computer library contents shows the USB connected device]

How can I access a USB connected device storage through Windows command line

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using `cd`/`chdir` you cannot change the current working directory (CWD) to one on a different drive unless first switching drives (2 steps) or including the `/d` switch as part of your command (1 step).

`cd /?` will display the command's help text.

##### From `C:\Users\jessy` to `E:\MyData`

```
     2 STEPS
  
1 |  C:\Users\jessy> E:
2 |  E:\> cd \MyData        // also 'cd E:\MyData' & 'cd MyData'
  |  E:\MyData>                         
    

     1 STEP

1 |  C:\Users\jessy> cd /d E:\MyData
  |  E:\MyData>
```

<sub>Credit to [Señor CMasMas](//superuser.com/users/1000631) for pointing out the shorter method.</sub>

#### Additional Reading

---

The way `cd` deals with drives and directories reflects its roots in DOS.  Windows really only has one current directory, however `cmd.exe` uses environment variables tied to that particular session to set and maintain it's own current directory for each drive separate from Windows as well as any other `cmd.exe` instances. If you'd like to read more, I have included a few links to get you started.

- A Current Directory for each drive?
  *[//ss64.com/nt/cd.html](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)*
- Why does each drive have its own current directory?
  *[//devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563)*
- How to get current working directory of another drive in Batch?
  *//stackoverflow.com/a/53078745*

#### Other Approaches

---

`pushd`  <sup>[ credit: [user @printf](https://superuser.com/users/17499/n0rd) ]</sup>

- Will traverse drives without additional command switches
- Stores the current directory for later use by the `popd` command
- See [Learn > Windows Server > Windows Commands > Reference > pushd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd)

Comment: Minor correction: `E:\> cd C:\Users\jessy` actually changes the "current" directory on drive C: to `\Users\jessy` -- so even though you're still on drive E:, the following `C:` command would put you into `C:\Users\jessy`.

Comment: Or just start using Powershell already where `cd e:\ ` would work.

Comment: Lots of fun stuff that's been forgotten. Related to this, a path of `E:something.txt` refers to a file in the current directory on E:, which may be different from the root :)

Comment: Yet another option is to use the `pushd` command, which can change both drive and directory: `pushd E:\ ` or `pushd E:\mydata` etc. (You can then later use the `popd` command to return to the original drive/directory.)

Comment: Another option to save you a line, you can do `E: && cd \MyData`